# Animation render only renders first frame, the rest are blank

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am new to blender and have been following a tutorial but unfortunately it was based on the old version of Blender. I have tried to render this 90 frame animation but unfortunately only the first frame comes out and the rest are blank! I have checked the composite, sequencer, check the frame in out rate, made sure camera is selected but nothing seems to work. I think it may be something to do with the compositor! If anyone could give me a help it would be much appreciated thank you all so much :)

Also, I dont know if this is a dumb question but would you be able to animate things that have been composited - ie the flare above.

Thank you all

[image]

Comment: What happens if you uncheck both (sequencer, compositing) in the [Post Processing Panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/post_process/panel.html)? Sure, the compositing won't render, but does the 3D View render at least?

Comment: Hi Leander, When I untick both boxes the renders come out as per normal..

Comment: So which one is responsible for the problem? Sequencer or Compositing? Please, more troubleshooting, more infos.

Comment: Hi Leander, when I render with only compositing box ticked, the render comes out a black screen but when I render only sequencer the render comes out with image without the flare. Does this mean that the compositing is the problem?

Comment: Yes, it must be. I cannot see the values of your compositing nodes on that images. Could you upload a larger/clearer image, or upload your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: Hi Leander, I cant seem to upload it on blender exchange but Ive uploaded it on a google drive thank you so much for taking time to help me much appreciated

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lXr7AYPduCjLAuPvJFzQQQtWsRUuNw4n/view?usp=sharing